# Force CollapsiblePanelExtender to Open when Printing

Tags: css, asp.net

I have a webpage with several `CollapsiblePanelExtender`s and `Accordion`s showing different tables of data.  When the user prints the page using their browser, I want to force all the `CollapsiblePanelExtender`s and `AccordionPane`s to extend, so that all the data is displayed on the printed copy.  I am aware of [@media print](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) in css, but I don't think that works on `CollapsiblePanelExtender`'s `collapsed` property.  Is there anything similar I could use in this case?  Will I be able to expand all the `AccordionPane`s at the same time for printing?

EDIT: I'd like to do this without having to add a "print" button with code to programmatically collapse my panels, so that I can support users who are used to just going to Menu -> Print in their browser window or keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create function on click of print button it just expand all of it and then triggers print?

Comment: My screen already has quite a few buttons on it, and I was hoping to not have to clutter it with another button just to print.  It may turn out that this is the only solution though.